# Создание RESTful API на php

Tags: php, rest

есть необходимость создать RESTful API на php. Не смог найти, есть ли в интернете какие-либо примеры по написанию CRUD API. С описанием какие паттерны проектирования в каких ситуациях использовать, и как лучше реализовать работу с базой данных в REST. Буду благодарен.

Comment: Можете прояснить что имеете ввиду под фразой: "как лучше реализовать работу с базой данных в REST" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Примеров в интернете много, на любой вкус. Можете посмотреть, например, https://klisl.com/php-api-rest.html или https://www.khtulhu.org.ua/veb-programmirovanie/719-sozdanie-restful-api-na-php.html а так же https://webdevkin.ru/posts/backend/restful-servis-na-nativnom-php

Comment: День добрый. У нас не приветствуются ответы-ссылки. Можете основное из этих статей перенести в ответ? А лучше пример.

Comment: Спасибо. Очень помогли.